# bash replacing character at certain position on a certain line

Tags: bash

I have a file that looks like this:

```
 [                                 
{                                 
     "ncyc" :  28817,         
    "icels" :    128,         
    "jcels" :    128,         
        "t" :   0.185896E-006,
       "dt" :   0.955602E-012,
   "dtcour" :   0.100000E+021,
      "dti" :   0.100000E+021,
      "dtc" :   0.262902E-011,
    "dtvol" :   0.239735E-010,
   "dthall" :   0.100000E+021,
  "dtlaser" :  -0.925596E+062,
    "dtmax" :   0.200000E-009,   
}
]
```

I want to delete the last comma of this file. It appears at the 14th line at position 34. I could do this manually if it was one file but I have to do this for 300 files

Comment: I'd suggest making the person who generated the broken JSON do it.

Comment: Not possible. Analyzing old data

Comment: Is it the 34th character of the 14th line in all 300 files? Is it always the last character of the line? Also, that looks like the 30th character...

Comment: Or is it always an array with a single object, and you want to remove the last comma in the object?

Comment: I have to remove the last comma

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162377/sed-remove-the-very-last-occurrence-of-a-string-a-comma-in-a-file

Comment: I ended up using python for it:  data[ndx-3]= data[ndx-3].replace(',', '')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. I was easily able to solve the question myself using Python:

```
  f=open(fjson, 'r')
  data= f.readlines()
  ndx=len(data)
  data[ndx-3]= data[ndx-3].replace(',', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

sed is your friend:

```
sed -i.bak '14s/,[[:blank:]]*$//' file ...
```

This is a bit fragile: it assumes the line to remove is always the 14th, not necessarily the line before the closing brace.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the platform `sed` or `awk` might have varying results, `perl` might be more flexible:

```
perl -i.bak -00pe 's/,(?!.*,)//s' file
```

> ```
> # , matches a comma.
> # (?!.*,) negative lookahead asserts no comma after matched comma. 
> # s is a DOTALL modifier matching newline characters also.
> ```

Comment: awesome. @wander95, this should be your accepted answer: it removes the last comma in the file.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163003/67817 is basically the same as this.

Comment: @TomFenech: It's too bad that it wasn't the accepted answer there, and it's buried so deep that it's probably easily missed.

Comment: I accepted this answer. But ended up using python as it was more readable. See below

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward ed one-liner:

```
ed foo.json <<EOF
?,?s/,\([^,]*\)$/\1/
wq
EOF
```

That line can be broken into an address and a command.

The address is `?,?`, namely the previous line matching the regular expression `,`.

The command is `s/re/replacement/`, where the regular expression is `,\([^,]*\)$` (a literal `,`, a captured group of zero or more character that are not `,`, and the end of the line), and the replacement is `\1` (the first captured group).

Technically it's a two-line ed script, `wq` to save and quit.

You could invoke this in a loop with `find`, for instance:

```
find . -name '*.json' | while read name ; do
ed -s $name <<EOF
H
[…ed commands…]
wq
EOF
done
```

I've also added `ed -s` to suppress the file size message, and `H` to output verbose errors instead of the infamous `?`.

Comment: Could you show how to use it, and perhaps explain what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra detail, it's a lot clearer now. If you're going to pipe into a `while read` loop (not ideal but convenient in this case), then it's worth using `read -r` and also quoting `$name` to avoid problems with awkward filenames. Better yet use `shopt -s globstar` and `for name in **/*.json` to do the recursive search (again, quoting `$name` within the loop).